# Solving $\ddot\Theta = -9.81\sin{\Theta},\ \ \Theta(0)=\frac{\pi}{4}, \ \ \dot{\Theta}(0) = 0.$ with RK method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, runge-kutta-methods

Given the Heun's RK method 
$$k_1 = f(t_n, y_n),$$
$$k_2 = f(t_n+h,y_n +k_1h),$$
$$y_{n+1} = y_n + \frac{h}{2}(k_1 + k_2)$$
I'm asked to "perform one RK step for the following equation"
$$\ddot\Theta = -9.81\sin{\Theta},\ \  \Theta(0)=\frac{\pi}{4}, \ \ \dot{\Theta}(0) = 0.$$

I'm not really sure how to how to do this. I attempt to rewrite the system to 
$$\dot{x_1} = x_2$$
$$\dot{x_2} = -9.81\sin{x_1}$$
by assigning $x_1 = \Theta, \ \ x_2 = \dot{\Theta}.$ Is this the right approach, if so how do I go from here?

Comment: You are correct. First rewrite the equation as a vector equation of order 1, then apply Heun's method to the new equation ($y_n$ is then a vector, and $f$ is vector-valued, apart from that the method is identical).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the system as

$$
\cases{\dot y_1 = y_2\\
\dot y_2 = a\sin y_1
}
$$

This is an autonomous system then the recursion equations can be written as

$$
\cases{
k_1 = f(Y_n)\\
k_2 = f(Y_n+h k_1)\\
Y_n = Y_{n-1}+\frac h2(k_1+k_2)
}
$$

with

$$
f(Y) = \cases{Y(2)\\ a\sin Y(1)}
$$

so with

$$
Y_0 = \cases{y^0_1\\ y^0_2}
$$

we have for $n=1$

$$
\cases{k_1 = \cases{y^0_2\\ a\sin y^0_1}\\ k_2 = \cases{a h \sin y^0_1+y^0_2\\ a\sin(y^0_1+h y^0_2)}\\
Y_1 = \cases{y^0_1+h y^0_2+\frac 12 ah^2\sin y^0_1\\ y^0_2+\sin(y^0_1+h y^0_2)+\frac 12 a h( \sin y^0_1+\sin(y^0_1+h y^0_2))}}
$$

etc.